# CoreData only updates after I restart the app?

Tags: swift, core-data

Hi I'm saving my data using the saveContext() that is generated with the AppDelegate template. My app records sets of locations when in background mode, and then when the app enters foreground I take those locations and store them in core data. Everything is saved and it stores but when I go to my view controller where I display them  it doesn't show unless I RESTART the app and come back to it.

```
 func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    if self.myLocations.count > 0 {

        let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
        let logEntity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "PostureLog", into: context)

        logEntity.setValue(self.errors, forKey: "logError")

        // populate log
        logEntity.setValue(Date(), forKey: "logDate")

        for i in 0...myLocations.count - 1 {
            let locationEntity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Location", into: context)

            // populate address
            locationEntity.setValue(myLocations[i].coordinate.latitude, forKey: "latitude")
            locationEntity.setValue(myLocations[i].coordinate.longitude, forKey: "longitude")

            // create relationship Location -> Log
            locationEntity.mutableSetValue(forKey: "log").add(logEntity)

        }

        self.saveContext()
        self.myLocations.removeAll()
        self.errors = 0


    }
}
```

**save context function**

```
 func saveContext () {
    let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
    if context.hasChanges {
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            let nserror = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably not refreshing your ViewController so it is still showing the old data until you restart.